# RETURN NEW is not working with UPDATE in arangodb

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to get all the documents updates in the aql but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
test -> {value:0}

FOR record in test
    UPDATE record with {value:1} in test 
      RETURN NEW
```

I get `[1501] syntax error, unexpected RETURN declaration near 'RETURN NEW' at position 3:5 (while parsing)`

Arangodb version 2.5.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2.5 you need to assign `NEW` to a temporary variable, e.g.

```
UPDATE ... LET x = NEW RETURN x
```

The simplified syntax is only available in 2.6.